# Alternation of Log in Form in drupal 7

Tags: users, forms

I want to alter the User login form of drupal 7. 
I want only two fields Email ID and password. I don't want a username field. Please any one have idea to how to do these changes in User login form.

Comment: Try to use : https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete the field in a form   you have to  print the form  either using dpm($form) or print_r($form) and there you will get the field of username use that field to unset in form_alter .

function [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

```
  if (form_id=="Your_form_id"){

      unset($form['the_field_you_dont_want']);

        }
   }
```

Comment: If it's an answer to the question. Please add some description to it.

Comment: Thank you sir for your suggestion but I am new in drupal development. So plz tell me in which file i have to dump the variable $form.